# MySql case statement returning multiple rows and multiple columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table

```
    -id   --col_1 -- col_2 -- col3 --col_4 -- col5
    ------------------------------------------------
     1       a         b       c       d       e
     2       a1        b1      c1      d1      e1
     3       a2        b2      c2      d2      e2
```

I need to check if col3 contains a value, if present i need to display col1 and col2 values and remaining values should be empty. Another condition if col4 contains value, i need to display only col2 and col5 values

```
    -id   --col_1 -- col_2 -- col3 --col_4 -- col5
    ------------------------------------------------
     1       a         b       c              
     1                 b1             d1      e1
     2       a1        b1      c1     
     2                 b1             d1      e1
     3       a2        b2      c2       
     3                 b2             d2      e2
```

I am unaware of which procedure to follow to achieve my requirement. I have used case statement, i have retrieved only one record for two conditions with only one column

```
SELECT    
CASE
    WHEN col3 != '' THEN col4        
END as a, 
CASE
    WHEN col4 != '' THEN col2
END as b
FROM table;
```

Any Help!..

Comment: your example has col2, col4 and col5 when col4 is not empty - please correct this condition ( or the example ). also clarify that by empty we are talking about the empty string : are there any nulls ? maybe also explain the context behind this question - do you need to store+solve the issue in this ( quite awkward ) way

Comment: In my example if i need to return one row for each condition. For 1st record, if col3 contains a value i need to get a record with only col1 and col2 remaining values i should not show. Again in 1st record if col4 has a value i need to generate a new record with another columns

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want `union all`:

```
select id, col1, col2, col3, NULL as col4, NULL as col5
from table
union all
select id, NULL, col2, NULL, col4, NULL as col5
from table ;
```

Comment: I have nearly 130 columns in my table. place at each column name will be difficult

Comment: so generate this sql from your table definition

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your worked for me. But i have 50 columns to show it will be difficult to keep null for some columns based on conditions. I have more than four conditions.

Comment: @user2083041 . . . I can only answer the question that is asked.  If you have another question (say with more columns), then you should ask that as another question.